# Proving that $\frac 1 2 t^3+\frac 1 2 t, (t\in \mathbb N)$ will always be a whole number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any way to show that $\dfrac 1 2 t^3+\dfrac 1 2 t$ will always be a whole number? Assuming that t is always a whole number greater than or equal to one? If i think about it logically it seems true but Im having trouble showing this mathematically. This is part of a larger proof that I've worked out but I cant seem to actually show that this is true, and hence my proof is not really complete. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably should have thought about this before posting but my problem is actually showing ((8/6)(t^3) + (4/6)(t)) is always whole

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: Yes i know modular arithmetic

Comment: So recall that $2\equiv -1\pmod 3.$

Comment: im sorry I do not see how that helps

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\dfrac12t^3+\dfrac12 t=\dfrac12(t^3+t)$$
Now show that $t^3+t$ is always even. (make two cases, one where $t=2k$ and the other where $t=2k+1$)

Comment: what if the fractions are something like 1/3 and 2/3?

Comment: @user2710184 Then you should factor the $t$s.

Comment: but the t's would be t^3 and t

Comment: @user2710184 For example, $\dfrac13t^3+\dfrac23t=t\left(\dfrac13t^2+\dfrac23\right)=t\left(\dfrac{t^2+2}{3}\right)=\dfrac{t^3+2t}3.$ Now prove that $t^3+2t$ is always divisible by $3$.

Comment: but its not always divisible by 3

Comment: @user2710184 It is, you can show it!

Comment: Using modular arithmetic?

Comment: @user2710184 Yes, or you can see that: $t^3+t=t(t^2+1)$. If $t$ is even, we're done. If $t$ is odd, then $t^2$ is also odd, so $t^2+1$ is even, and we're done!